# Url drag and drop on winforms control from IE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to receive a drop from the URL in IE in a winforms control.
I get no drag enter event.
Does anyone know ho to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Drag and Drop Functionality WebBrowser Control Winforms C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361007/implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality-webbrowser-control-winforms-c)

Comment: Is this on Vista/7? If so it might actually be UAC issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the AllowDrop property on the control you wish to drag into to True.