# Drag Drop event on winforms webbrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Inside a winforms application I want to start a drag on a table into a winforms browser control.

I am not able to register the drapenter and drag drop event since this is giving me a NotSupported Exception. However if I set AllowDrop to True and drag a file into the webbrowser control it navigates to the file. So dragging seems to be supproted somewhere in the code. 
I want to be able to get any drag enter / drag drop event and read it in my C# code.

What is the best way to do this?

I already tried to use the suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361007/implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality-webbrowser-control-winforms-c-sharp)  that was supplied here but my get drop target was not called.

What is the best way to proceed? What am I missing or should be reading about?